# Reading XML and storing it in SQL Server. Getting duplicates

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to read XML feed from the URL and store it in the database. The XML format looks like this:

```
<response version="2">
  <totalresults>1249943</totalresults>
  <results>
    <result>
      <jobtitle>Call Center </jobtitle>
      <company>CVS Health</company>
      <city>Work at Home</city>
    </result>

    <result>
      <jobtitle>Java Programmer</jobtitle>
      <company>Jonah Group</company>
      <city>Toronto</city>
    </result>
  </results>
</response>
```

And I am trying to store job title, company, and city for all the jobs. There are millions of jobs. Here is my code in C#

```
public override void getJobsFromSource()
{
    string url = @"http://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?publisher=5566998848654317&v=2&q=%22%22&filter=1%22%22&limit=25";
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(url);
    int totalResults = int.Parse(doc.SelectSingleNode("response /totalresults").InnerText);

    for (int i = 0; i < totalResults; i += 25)
    {
        string newUrl = $@"http://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?publisher=5566998848654317&v=2&q=%22%22&filter=1&limit=25&start={i}";
        doc.Load(newUrl);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        XmlNodeReader xmlReader = new XmlNodeReader(doc);

        while (xmlReader.ReadToFollowing("results"))
        {
            ds.ReadXml(xmlReader);
        }

        if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = "data source=10.0.0.76;initial catalog=JobSearchDB;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=bonddbl07;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework";
            con.Open();

            SqlBulkCopy sbc = new SqlBulkCopy(con);
            sbc.DestinationTableName = "IndeedJob";

            sbc.ColumnMappings.Clear();
            sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("jobtitle", "jobtitle");
            sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("company", "company");
            sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("city", "city");
            sbc.WriteToServer(ds.Tables[0]);
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that while jobs are unique, I am getting many duplicates in my tables. Duplicates come in random numbers whenever I run the program. Where am going wrong?

Comment: Use a webbrowser to go to the url.  You are using only the job title where companies often post many jobs under the same title.  Use the jobkey to get unique numbers for each posting.

Comment: I am not showing all the tags here in my question. One of the tags is <jobkey> and is unique. Indeed website assign a unique key to each job.However in my table i am seeing many duplicates with the same jobkey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The webpage definitely has duplicates.  I verified with code below.  The webpage doesn't appear to have well formed xml so I had to modify your code to be able to read webpage.  Using Linq I was able to remove the duplicates.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet("Jobs");
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            getJobsFromSource();
            DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
            dt = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field <string>("jobkey")).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).OrderBy(y => y.Field<string>("jobkey")).CopyToDataTable();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
        public void getJobsFromSource()
{
            string url = @"http://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?publisher=5566998848654317&v=2&q=%22%22&filter=1%22%22&limit=25";
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(url);
            int totalResults = int.Parse(doc.SelectSingleNode("response /totalresults").InnerText);
            for (int i = 0; i < totalResults; i += 25)
            {
                string newUrl = @"http://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?publisher=5566998848654317&v=2&q=%22%22&filter=1&limit=25&start={i}";

                XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
                settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.None;
                settings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;
                XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(newUrl, settings);

                while (!xmlReader.EOF)
                {
                    if (xmlReader.Name != "result")
                    {
                        xmlReader.ReadToFollowing("result");
                    }
                    if(!xmlReader.EOF)
                    {
                        ds.ReadXml(xmlReader);
                    }
                }
            }
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are assuming that the results are not going to change while you are parsing the results, but this may not be the case.  If a new posting comes in, it may appear at the beginning of the list, and push the rest of your results down one.  This causes the last item on a page to be duplicated on the next page.

Also, there doesn't appear to be a firm order to the query you are making.  It is possible the existing results are changing order while you are searching through.  Again, if items shift around in the search, it may lead to either duplicates or skipped items.